# Circuit for simulation

Tags: simulation, passive-networks, pspice, transient

Can someone please help solving for my circuit connection, I'm new to this and somehow didnt manage to simulate the circuit correctly as the software stated this

> Warning: Inductor-voltage source loop found: L1, Vdc4. Since inductors are short-circuited during the DC bias point calculation, the loop will cause a problem for most analyses. Consider breaking the loop by inserting a small series resistor.

. This topics is about RLC Transient Simulation.

Original question : In the circuit shown below, Vo = 5V, and Io = 0A. Plot vc versus t for R1=1.923Ohm at t>0.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual question/issue you're facing?

Comment: When I try to simulate, it does said "Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving V_V1. Circuit has errors, simulation aborted."

Comment: I'm not familiar with PSpice's particularities, but you may need to consider adding a tiny resistor, or forcing the appropriate initial conditions manually; such a circuit with an ideal inductor and ideal source is a somewhat pathological case involving some indeterminacy when solving for the DC operating point.

Comment: What I thought was my circuit connection was wrong, isnt ? I dont know how to make Io = 0A.

Comment: There might be a way to encode the initial condition in the program inputs, but I don't know for PSpice. Perhaps someone else knows. As for the circuit itself, it's slightly wrong (should have a pulse source that goes  0->5 and stays on); it's still pathological for the reason that it has ideal inductors and voltage sources (which doesn't happen irl)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is intended to specify the initial capacitor voltage `Vo=5 at t=0` and initial inductor current `Io=0 at t=0`. Your circuit, as drawn on the right, seems to keep the voltage at 5 forever.

This is easy to fix with a **Time-Controlled Switch** that opens or closes at t=0. In fact, we'll use two of them: SW1 to disconnect the voltage source, and SW2 to connect the inductor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6m58l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The simulator produces the following plot:

[image: RLC with initial conditions]

Using time-controlled switches that switch at t=0 is a straightforward way both to think about and to specify initial conditions.

Comment: So how about Io = 0A ? I try to simulate like your suggestion but Io is not equal to 0A but a really small current.

Comment: When I run the simulation and add `I(L1.nA)` to the plot outputs, I see that the inductor current is zero at `t=0`. You could change the switching time of both SW1 and SW2 to be at `t=0.1` and this will make it even more obvious.

Comment: Hey, I'm so grateful that you help me to go throughout this simulation with great solution. Thank you sir !

Answer (score 0):

Since L is ideal, there is no current limit or steady state.  It is always a good practice to use real DCR values in real simulations and real ESR for e-caps. They are found in datasheets.

The current keeps ramping up dI/dt= V/L

I tried this on a 5 MVA transformer to measure its 22H primary using a Li Ion cell on the 22kV line in a factory . This also causes a little Remanence (stored Magnetic field) but it was so slow, I could measure the DC inductance and compare with an RLC meter at 60 Hz, 10kHz and 100kHz as it changes.I stopped at 10A then reversed it for the time. Releasing the battery made a nice little arc.

For example a 240mA 1H choke is 50 Ohms.

A 1mF non-polar plastic cap would be huge but very low ESR, while a nonxpolarized general purpose e-cap would be about 200 to 400us = ESR*C.

Simulation errors tend to be from using ideal parts that give unrealistic results, but for training purposes, that’s what they teach.(!)

Just remember that everything has some resistance.